# tkinter textbox not printing list correctly?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here's the part of my code that's of interest-

```
   videoIdeasList = [
"test",
"test 2",
"test 3",
```

]

And then

```
    elif messageWindow.get("1.0", "end-1c") == "Video Ideas":
        chatWindow.insert(END, " >>> See Ideas \n \n")
        chatWindow.insert(END, "Ok, here's your list of ideas.\n")
        chatWindow.insert(END, videoIdeasList)
        chatWindow.insert(END, "\nAnything else I can help with? \n \n")
        chatWindow.see(END)
```

when I run it, the output looks like this...

" >>> Video Ideas

Ok, here's your list of ideas.

test {test 2} {test 3}

Anything else I can help with?"

And when I put a star in front of the videoIdeasList variable it returns testtest3 with no new line and not showing the test2 part of the list.

Basically how do I make it so I can display all the items on the list on their own lines?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: convert it to string : `" ".join(videoIdeasList)`

Comment: @fukanchik Thank you! That got rid of the { } but didn't put the list on new lines. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Osprey in that case try `"\n".join(videoIdeasList)`